# How to test a REST service that uses JWT in SoapUI?

Tags: rest, soapui, jwt

I'm implementing some REST services. All my tests are made using SoapUI.
Recently I decided to adopt JSON Web Token (JWT) for authentication but I could not find any support for this on SoapUI (native install or plugins, nothing).

I found some online generators like http://jwtbuilder.jamiekurtz.com/ but fill all fields, copy/paste on SoapUI again and again for every testcase is not productive at all.

I'm wondering if there is a way to test JWT stuff in SoapUI or if maybe I need another tool. Any advice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've found a semi-automatic way to keep a valid JWT token across TestCases without losing too much time, using an external file containing the token.

1. Have an external tool generating a valid JWT token into a file.
2. Open your project in SoapUI and add a `jwt` variable with the value

   `${=new File('/path/to/token_file.txt').text}`

   [image]
3. In your requests, reference your variable as a JWT header with the value

   `${#Project#jwt}`

   [image]

When the token expire, just relaunch the generator script, and SoapUI will automatically load the new token.

Answer (score 0):

SoapUI will call your authentication server and fetch the token, then it will automatically put that token into authorization header (`Bearer <token>`).

```
Add new authorization>OAuth 2>Resource owner password credential grant
```

Then add your username and password into both client and resource section. Finally , put your token end-point as access token url and save the authorization  profile to use in other test cases.