# Retrieve token from a response and pass in following request in SoapUI

Tags: groovy, jwt, token, soapui

I have access token say for ex- 
`"AccessToken": "ziZePotBKpjYh5cMEK1swRZVXJl6ky0r6M4YDNv+TCv+6rmy+N36cm/R"` 
 retrieved from my POST request.

Now I need to pass this access token as JWT token in next GET request.
So how do I write the `groovy script` for this, for passing this access token as JWT token to next GET request?

Comment: First save the value to a custom property at test case or test suite level (if you want to use that in multiple test cases) and use custom property in the next requests where the value is needed. Please look at the documentation.

Comment: Please provide some link or document here.Please help because i am stuck since two days in the same as i tried multiple java script to convert my access token to JWT token pease help

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33534979/how-to-test-a-rest-service-that-uses-jwt-in-soapui

Answer (score 0):

Store the string in a test case property:

```
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("AccessToken", "ziZePotBKpjYh5cMEK1swRZVXJl6ky0r6M4YDNv+TCv+6rmy+N36cm/R")
```

Then use the prop value in the request like so:

```
${#TestCase#AccessToken}
```

Comment: Sorry but as i told i cant pass this token straightaway lik ethis ...2 things are there 1) Need to covert this token to JWT token 2) Pass the JWT token to next GET request. Now these two steps capturing tokens and converting to JWT token should be automated through script groovy script so how i can do that..?? Now the answer you have mentioned that we can do when we directly passing the token but here situation is different as explained above,So please advise accordingly .